# Running time for recursive and iterative

Tags: algorithm

I know there are some algorithms which take same running time for both recursive and iterative strategy. But I can't decide on that base.

Is that possible an algorithm with both recursive and iterative strategy will always take same running time?

Answer (score 3):

Every recursive algorithm can be reduced to an iterative algorithm (with the same running time). 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursion_versus_iteration

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if an algorithm can be optimized to use tail recursion, then it can be converted to iterative without extra code, thus will have the same execution time.

Answer (score 0):

It can be of the same time complexity but the constant overhead will probably differ (recursive will probably be more expensive). In addition, recursion adds an extra space complexity that's not present if iterative approach is used.

Comment: Well it depends. Converting an arbitrary recursive algorithm to iterative involves creating an explicit stack structure. So the space complexity doesn't change. It's only for tail recursion that no extra space is required.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Agree for general case. However I think the question target is a bit different and it's not about ability to convert but rather about a comparison of 2 given implementations - e.g., naive recursive factorial vs. iterative.